# refering to a transposed column name which is referenced by a macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

referring to below code, after I transpose a data-set (output qc2), I tried to create a percentage column (most_recent_wk_percent_change) but the result of the column is 12.5% with two new columns - &week3. and &week2. created. The expected result is to calculate based on the values in week2 and week3 columns.  I know the problem could be the referencing of the two columns in the percentage calculation (==>  ( &week3. - &week2.)/&week2.;) , but I couldn't put my head to the correction. pls advise :)

```
%let week1 = 7;
%let week2 = 8;
%let week3 = 9;


proc sql;
create table qc as
select t_week, prod_cat, sum(sales) as sales
from master_table
where t_week in (&week1.,&week2.,&week3.)
group by 1,2
order by 2;
quit;


proc transpose data= qc out=qc2;
format 
by prod_cat ;
id t_week;
run;

data qc2;
set qc2; 
format most_recent_wk_percent_change PERCENT7.1;
most_recent_wk_percent_change =    ( &week3. - &week2.)/&week2.;
run;
```

---

```
qc:
t_week|prod_cat|sales
7|cat|100
8|cat|200
9|cat|300
7|dog|150
8|dog|400
9|dog|300
7|rat|200
8|rat|600
9|rat|300

qc2: (TRANSPOSED TABLE --> note the column name of 7,8,9. (which is expected)
prod_cat|7|8|9
cat|100|200|300
dog|150|400|300
rat|200|600|300

qc2: (i wanted to get the change in % )
prod_cat|7|8|9|most_recent_wk_percent_change|&week2.|&week3.
cat|100|200|300|12.5%|.|.|    ==> 12.5% is wrong. should be 50% (300-200)/(200)
dog|150|400|300|12.5%|.|.|    ==> 12.5% is wrong. should be -25%
rat|200|600|300|12.5%|.|.|    ==> 12.5% is wrong. should be -50%
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You should include some example input data, posted as text within your question, not as an image, and the corresponding output data you are trying to produce.

Comment: Why `&tweek2.` ? Perhaps you meant to have `&week2.` in the final data step ?  What are the values of t_week ? If t_week is numeric the corresponding column name created via `id` will have leading underscore.  Perhaps you should examine the transpose output before using it ?  Can you add to the question the proc contents output for data set `qc2` ?  Put down the drink, pick up the keyboard.

Comment: i've added the data output and result :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you are doing or why, but if you have set `VALIDVARNAME=any` and the actual name of your variable is `7` and you try to use it in SAS code like this:

```
ratio = 7/8 ;
```

Then SAS will assume you mean the numeric value 7.

You need to use a name literal instead.

```
ratio = '7'n / '8'n ;
```

So you want

```
most_recent_wk_percent_change = ("&week3"n-"&week2"n)/"&week2"n;
```

If instead the actual name of the variable is `_7` then you need to code this way.

```
most_recent_wk_percent_change = (_&week3.-_&week2.)/_&week2.;
```

Comment: Hi, I meant to transpose  the t_week column values of 7,8 and 9 into column names, via the IF keyword in transpose. And then using the percentage formula to calculate changes  of values under column '9' from column '8'. The first 3 let lines of 7,8,9 are meant to allow user input so that the rest of the program can take the values to run .

Comment: Depending how you have set the value of the `VALIDVARNAME` option then proc transpose will either name the columns as `"7"n` or `_7`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a keep statement to your last data step, this will only keeps the columns you want in the output.

```
data qc2 (keep= most_recent_wk_percent_change prod_cat);
set qc2; 
format most_recent_wk_percent_change PERCENT7.1;
most_recent_wk_percent_change =    ( &week3. - &tweek2.)/&week2.;
run;
```